# If a subspace M is closed and dense in an inner product space V, does V = M?

Tags: general-topology, inner-products

The question said, if M is closed and dense in V, what conclusions can be drawn about M and V? I am assuming that these sets must be equal just by intuition and trying to visualize it. This is because every sequence is convergent to some point still in M, yet every $m\in M$ is within a neighborhood of any $v \in V$. So, to me, it seems clear that they must be equal. Are there any counterexamples to this, though?

Comment: Is your argument correct? If so, it is not possible for counterexamples to exist!

Comment: I guess that is my question :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is dense, $\overline{M}=V$, if $M$ is close then $M=\overline{M}$, for transitivity $M=V$

Comment: Thanks! That is concise and elegant, exactly what I was looking for!